# How to configure NiFi InvokeHTTP to post insert in Clickhouse

Tags: apache-nifi, clickhouse

I've in a NiFi attribute the full INSERT command that works with CURL:

```sh
echo "INSERT INTO default.PERFTEST_BUFFER VALUES (1, '2020-04-09 19:06:02', 48.8644, 'A')" \
  | curl 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8123/?' --data-binary @-
```

Insert in Attribut :

```sql
INSERT INTO default.PERFTEST_BUFFER 
VALUES (1, '2020-04-09 19:06:02', 48.8644, 'A')
```

I can't figure out what should be all the parameters of the InvokeHTTP processor.

I've used for the first two :

```
  POST

  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8123/
```

then I'm lost.
Any idea how to configure it ?

Comment: put `INSERT INTO ...` into flow file content prior to InvokeHTTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I made it work thanks to daggett and and example here :

https://github.com/zezutom/NiFiByExample

Use before the InvokeHTTP a processor ReplaceText that replace the flowfile content by the variable "Insert" value that have the full Insert command

- Search Value        (?s)(^.*$)
- Replacement Value   ${Insert}

So the flow file content is

```
INSERT INTO default.PERFTEST_BUFFER VALUES (1, '2020-04-09 19:06:02', 48.8644, 'A')
```

Follow by a processor InvokeHTTP the following parameters

- HTTP Method             POST
- Remote URL              http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8123/
- SSL Context Service     No value set
- Connection Timeout      5 secs
- Read Timeout            15 secs
- Include Date Header     True
- Follow Redirects        True
- Attributes to Send      No value set
- Basic Authentication Username   No value set
- Basic Authentication Password   No value set
- Proxy Configuration Service     No value set
- Proxy Host              No value set
- Proxy Port              No value set
- Proxy Type              http
- Proxy Username          No value set
- Proxy Password          No value set
- Put Response Body In Attribute  No value set
- Max Length To Put In Attribute  256
- Use Digest Authentication       false
- Always Output Response          true
- Add Response Headers to Request false
- Content-Type                    ${mime.type}
- Send Message Body               true
- Use Chunked Encoding            false
- Penalize on "No Retry"          false
- Use HTTP ETag                   false
- Maximum ETag Cache Size         10MB

Answer (score 0):

If your query is static you can pass it in the query string in the encoded format:

```sh
# GET

curl 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8123/?query=INSERT%20INTO%20default.PERFTEST_BUFFER%20VALUES%20%281%2C%20%272020-04-09%2019%3A06%3A02%27%2C%2048.8644%2C%20%27A%27%29'


# POST

curl -d '' 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8123/?query=INSERT%20INTO%20default.PERFTEST_BUFFER%20VALUES%20%281%2C%20%272020-04-09%2019%3A06%3A02%27%2C%2048.8644%2C%20%27A%27%29'
```

It needs to pass the required values to just two params: *HTTP Method* and *Remote URL* of *InvokeHTTP*-processor.